Remove Direct access from Azure DevOps organization's access level through an API or a Script
I need help with Removing Direct access from Azure DevOps organization's access level through an API or a Script, with the select feature we are only able to remove only 100 users but we have more than 4ooo users.
Requirement: A mechanism in which only direct access is removed, so the Group rules take are enforced.
Thanks
Tried to remove members from the UI but we can remove only members in multiples of hundreds, also stakeholder Direct access is assigned to members when they are added by the Project admin to any Azure DevOps Project.
We use Group rules for access levels however Direct access takes precedence and we have to remove direct access for multiple users when they are assigned Project permissions directly.

There is no public documented Azure DevOps CLI/API available for remove direct assignments.
However, when I try to manually remove direct assignments on the web UI of Azure DevOps (Organization Settings > Users), if I open the "Developer tools" window of the browser, from the Network tab, I can see below API is called.

HTTP URI
POST https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/<organization>/_apis/MEMInternal/RemoveExplicitAssignment?select=grouprules&ruleOption=0&api-version=5.0-preview.1


Request Body
[
   "<user ID>"
]




Below I will share a sample of PowerShell script to show how to use above API to remove direct assignments for each user in an Azure DevOps organization:

Call the API "Member Entitlements - Search Member Entitlements" to list all the users in the organization.

Call above API in a loop to remove direct assignments for each user.

NOTE: The organization owner cannot be removed direct assignments. This also cannot be manually removed on the web UI of Azure DevOps. So, when calling the API in the loop, you also need to exclude the organization owner.

Below is the PowerShell script. I have tried it, and it can work fine.


$organization = "xxxx"  # Name of your Azure DevOps organization.
$ownerMailAddress = "xxxx"  # Email address of organization owner.

$pat = "xxxx"  # Your Personal Access Token.
$base64Token = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $pat)))

$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic $base64Token"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

$continuationToken = "first_api_call"
while ($continuationToken -ne $null)
{
    $uri_list_users = $null
    if ("$continuationToken" -eq "first_api_call") {
        $uri_list_users = "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/${organization}/_apis/memberentitlements?api-version=7.1-preview.2"
    }
    else {
        $uri_list_users = "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/${organization}/_apis/memberentitlements?continuationToken=${continuationToken}&api-version=7.1-preview.2"
    }

    # List all users in the Azure DevOps organization.
    $users = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $uri_list_users -Headers $headers

    # Remove direct assignments for each user, exclude the organization owner.
    foreach ($user in $users.items)
    {
        $userMailAddress = $user.member.mailAddress
        if ("$userMailAddress" -ne "$ownerMailAddress")
        {
            Write-Host "-----------------------------------"
            Write-Host "Remove direct assignments for user:"
            $userName = $user.member.displayName
            $userId = $user.id
            Write-Host $userName
            Write-Host $userId

            $uri_remove_direct_assign = "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/${organization}/_apis/MEMInternal/RemoveExplicitAssignment?select=grouprules&ruleOption=0&api-version=5.0-preview.1"

            $body = @($userId) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5 -AsArray

            Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $uri_remove_direct_assign -Headers $headers -Body $body
        }
    }

    $continuationToken = $users.continuationToken
}

You need to pass the following information to the script:

Pass the name of your Azure DevOps organization to the variable "$organization".

Pass the email address of organization owner to the variable "$ownerMailAddress". You can find the name and email of the organization owner on the "Organization Settings" > "Overview" page.

Pass the PAT (Personal Access Token) of a user to the variable "$pat". The user should be a member of PCA (Project Collection Administrators) group. The organization owner is PCA by default.

NOTE: When I set the scope of the PAT as "Member Entitlement Management (Read & write)", it can successfully call the first API to list all the users, but gets 401 error when calling the second API to remove direct assignments. After I changed the scope to "Full access", all the API gets worked.



After calling the script, do not forget to reopen/refresh the "Organization Settings" > "Users" page.

